# Why aren't I getting suggestions for fields of a function argument with other overloads?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js, intellisense

I'm working in a JavaScript codebase with Sequelize models that have types documented using TypeScript declaration files (`.d.ts`). I'm using `mode.update()` to update some properties on the object:

This problem can be reproduced as follows:

```
import { Model } from "sequelize";
let model: Model<{foo:number,bar:string,baz:boolean}>;

model.update({
   // start typing "foo", "bar", or "baz" and observe
   // that suggestions do not appear.
   
})
```

I expected that when starting to type "foo", "bar", or "baz", I'd get suggestions to complete those fields that I declared in what I passed as the `TModelAttributes` generic argument. Instead, it doesn't show those fields at all in the suggestions list.

Interestingly, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> before I start typing the key, it works as expected.

What is causing this issue, and what can I do to get the behavior I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the type declarations emitted for sequelize's `Model#update` method:

```
  public update<K extends keyof TModelAttributes>(key: K, value: TModelAttributes[K] | Col | Fn | Literal, options?: InstanceUpdateOptions<TModelAttributes>): Promise<this>;
  public update(
    keys: {
        [key in keyof TModelAttributes]?: TModelAttributes[key] | Fn | Col | Literal;
    },
    options?: InstanceUpdateOptions<TModelAttributes>
  ): Promise<this>;
```

If I comment out the first overload, things start working as you would like them to, so something about this overload is making it difficult for ts-server to confidently give the suggestion that you expect it to give.

I don't think it's logically impossible for the behaviour that you expect here to be achieved, since it can be inferred by the fact that I'm passing something in the first argument to `update` that already fails to match the first overload of `update` (the one for setting a specific key-value pair) because none of the keys I have declared in the `TModelAttributes` generic argument I specified are of object type, which should mean that the first overload can be ruled out, and suggestions based on remaining possible overloads.

But I don't think there's much you can do about this right now and on your own other than show this MRE to the TypeScript maintainers in an issue ticket and ask if editor facilities can be improved here. The issue ticket has now been raised at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53069.

... Unless you never use the key-value overload of `update` and you decide you feel okay nuking that line from your downloaded sequelize type decleration file, but quite frankly, that's just a terrible solution all around. You'd need to remember to do that every time you do a fresh `npm install` or update the package.

Comment: I can confirm that commenting out that overload does fix the issue. I created an issue in the TypeScript repository: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53069. Thanks!